# How to set where in values by array in Database client spring boot webflux

Tags: database, spring-webflux

I am using webflux and database Client in Spring boot.I have a String type like this
String status="Quoted,Order,Bought";
I want to set these values in (where in) caluse.Code is like this.

```
String status="Quoted,Order,Bought";
 @Override
public Flux<Quotation> statusCreatedBy(Pageable pageable, String createdBy,String status) {
    RowsFetchSpec<Quotation> list =db.sql("SELECT e.id AS e_id, e.amount AS e_amount, e.description AS e_description FROM quotation e  WHERE e.created_by = '"+createdBy+"' and e.name in ('"+status+"') LIMIT "+pageable.getPageSize()+" OFFSET "+pageable.getOffset()).map(this::process);
    return list.all();
}
```

I got sql syntax like this.

```
where e.name in ('Quoted,Order,Bought')
```

what I want is

```
where e.name in ('Quoted','Order','Bought')
```

Please kindly guide me to fix this.Also I don't know the number of array values.Sometime status can 4 or 5 value depending on the user.For example,

```
String status='Quoted,Order,Bought,Cancel,Transfer' or Status='Quoted'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `","` with `"','"` using:

```
status.replace(",", "','")
```

So your statement looks like:

```
"… and e.name in ('" + status.replace(",", "','") + "') …"
```

---

Although hand building SQL will work, it’s best practice (and easier IMHO) to use a library to substitute variables into placeholders. Consider using JPA, Hibernate etc,
.

Comment: Many Thanks Bohemian. You save my life. It works.